# can exec work with while loop of cursor?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

```
Declare @var varchar(200)
set @var='select max(val) from floattable'

declare c1 cursor
for select id from floattable

declare @val int

Fetch next from c1 into @val
open c1
while @@Fetch_Status=0
begin
  update floattable set tagval=exec(@var) where id=@id
  Fetch next from c1 into @val
end
```

SQL Server 2005 throwing an error 'incorrect syntax near exec'.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use Exec like you used it in that piece of code.
The syntax for [Exec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx) is like this:

```
Execute a character string
{ EXEC | EXECUTE } 
    ( { @string_variable | [ N ]'tsql_string' } [ + ...n ] )
    [ AS { LOGIN | USER } = ' name ' ]
[;]
```

If you want to return some value, there might be an option by using [sp_executesql](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx):

```
EXECUTE sp_executesql
    @SQLString, @ParmDefinition,
    @level = @IntVariable, @max_titleOUT=@max_title OUTPUT;
```